# Compute the minimal and maximal subset of a set of sets

Tags: code-golf, code-challenge, set-theory

Let S be a set of sets, for example `S = {{A},{B},{A,B}}`. A maximal subset, `Max`, is an element of S such that no other set in S strictly includes `Max`. So in this example, {A,B} is a maximal subset as none of the other sets strictly contain {A,B}.

A minimal subset, `Min`, is an element of S such that no other set in S is strictly included in `Min`. So in this example, {A} and {B} are both minimal subsets as none of the other sets are strictly contained in {A} or {B}.

### Function input and output

Input: A set `S` which contains an arbitrary number of other sets. These sets can have any range of alphanumeric values and can include the empty set. Example of inputs: `{{a1},{a2},{a1,a2},{a2,a3}}` and `{{},{a1},{a2}}`

Outputs: A value for `Min`, which corresponds to the minimal subset as defined above and a value for `Max`  as defined by the maximal subset as defined above. These two outputs should be printed and it should be clear which is the `Min` and which is the `Max`, examples given in the test cases.

The output is what is important here, as long as you can achieve it, you may use any range of functions.

### Test cases

```
{{a1},{a2},{a1,a2},{a2,a3}}         => Min = {{a1},{a2}}, Max = {{a1,a2},{a2,a3}}
{{a1},{a1,a3},{a1,a4}}              => Min = {{a1}}, Max = {{a1,a3},{a1,a4}}
{{a1},{a1,a4,a5},{a2,a3,a5}}        => Min = {{a1}}, Max = {{a1,a4,a5},{a2,a3,a5}}
{{},{a1},{a2}}                      => Min = {{}}, Max = {{a1},{a2}}
{{}, {a1}, {a2, a4}}                => Min = {{}}, Max = {{a1}, {a2, a4}}
{{}, {a1}, {a2, a3}, {a2, a3, a4}}  => Min = {{}}, Max = {{a1}, {a2, a3, a4}}
```

Comment: Can we choose which values to use for the sets (e.g. positive integers) or do we have to support arbitrary values?

Comment: This challenge seems to be missing a lot of information.  It provides two definitions but no additional information.  I can *infer* that we are supposed to implement `Max` and `Min` and that this is code-golf.  But I can't infer a lot of other things.  Are we supposed to make one function/code which takes an input and outputs both, or two separate ones to be counted together?  If they are separate can they share some code, e.g. a helper function, or must they be two entirely divorced pieces of code.

Comment: I'm going to temporarily close this question until it at the very least clarifies these points.  This is a temporary measure and can be reversed by me or by other users of the site once things have been clarified.

Comment: Clarified a bit

Comment: Welcome to CGCC. Note that the winning criterion needs to be [stated](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13091/92901) in the text of the challenge (not just as tags). If the winning criterion is just 'shortest code wins' then [tag:code-challenge] doesn't apply.

Comment: *Function...* and *These two outputs should be printed and it should be clear which is the Min and which is the Max*: That's not how things generally work on this site. Check out [I/O methods allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/78410). A submission is usually allowed to be a function or a full program. When multiple things are to be output, a submission may wrap them in an array or a tuple to return them, print them, or use "out arguments", etc.

Comment: The description makes it sounds to me like we output only one minimal and one maximal subset, whereas the test cases seem to list all of each.